# Can resistance to rot be improved with home heating?

Tags: wood, thermally-modified

There is a [process](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00884121/document) by which wood is heated several times in the absence of oxygen to improve its mechanical properties and to make it more resistant to rot.
See also these questions [1](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3460/does-burning-wood-increase-any-mechanical-proprieties?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/are-there-any-serious-and-non-obvious-disadvantages-to-thermally-modified-wood?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Would it be possible to get some of the benefits by heating wood in a home oven to around 200 degrees centigrade? Specifically I would like to make pine planks less resistant to rot so I can use them outside.

The original process requires the absence of oxygen and demands high pressure, none of which are possible in a kitchen oven.

Comment: The *very* limited size of material you can process in this way aside (how big is your oven??) you're basically just going to dry out the wood more. There are plenty of other options to improve resistance to insect attack and decay for common softwoods, #1 of which is of course to use pressure-treated material. But there are plenty of paint-on preservatives (including actual paint!) if you'd prefer not to work with pressure-treated material.

Comment: @Graphus I'm replacing the seating on a small bistro chair, so the planks are small :-) 35 cm length. But will the last longer outside if 'baked'? Could it catch fire?

Comment: If you dry at 200°C for long enough yes, the wood would catch fire (same way food can if cooked for too long). But with wood that would take a while so I think you'd notice the scorched smell long before the wood ignites. Anyone you could try this, but I don't think there's any benefit to be gained and if you over-bake the wood it will become significantly more brittle. *"I'm replacing the seating on a small bistro chair"* The best advice I can give here is to use oak, or another resistant hardwood.

Comment: Late comment but just add 3 layers of linseed oil. after applying linseed oil, dry off the remaining oil after 15 minutes (which is the oil that wasn't absorbed - the remaining oil shouldn't dry up or the surface will be sticky) repeat 3 days until you have 3 layers. Then add 1 layer after each year being outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this question:

> Can I heat-treat wood in a similar manner to the quoted paper and get
> the results I want (resistance to rot), with none of the downsides mentioned in the same
> paper?

The short answer is, no.

For your purpose there isn't much benefit, even if it *would* work (which it will not), because many of the benefits of using wood for a chair are also changed with this process. Most of the strength was reduced, and especially the elasticity. There was a gain in compression strength that you didn't need in the first place. (A chair will only see so much compression testing from a human sitting in it. Elasticity and resistance to racking are way more important for furniture like this.)

As for the rot-resistance, I remain unconvinced. It reduced some fungal attacks, probably by removing or converting the only part of the wood that fungus likes to eat. Basically, it did the job the fungus wanted to do, just quicker?

But what about all the other things in the world that want to eat wood? Fungus is only one aspect of what we call "rot". A good part of wood breakdown is simply exposure to elements that cause the wood to move away from glue and fasteners, and UV light breaking down the connections in the wood itself. Insects like ants and wasps would still be interested in making paper from your furniture, if they get the chance.

The authors make this very clear:

> Although heat treatment is an effective modification method to
> improve  the  dimensional  stability and resistance  against fungal
> attack there are undesired side effects, mainly due to the high
> temperatures involved (150–280◦C). Reductions of mechanical properties
> of wood were noticed after heat treatment, e.g. the resistance to
> shock, modulus of elasticity (MOE), bending strength (MOR), compressive
> resistance, shear strength, and abrasion resistance.

However, more to the point, this process does not allow the carbon in the wood to easily combine with oxygen (which carbon really wants to do). So in your oxygen-rich oven all you would be making is really, really slow charcoal. You would not get the purported advantages of whatever mechanical or chemical process is going on at low-heat low-oxygen environments.

So, to recap:

1. You can't really reproduce what they are doing in this paper.
2. Even if you could, you don't get any real advantage in doing so.

Comment: I was wondering how the OP was going to evacuate the oxygen from her oven - glad you covered that. Not too many household ovens can hold a vacuum.

Comment: Mine can barely hold heat.